# Cypress get the text of an API response parameter

Tags: api, cypress

I want to get the number from the URL located in an API response.
For that I get the URL, but I don't know how to convert that in to text to extract the number.

```
cy.intercept('GET', 'http://viasphere.localhost/documents/page_elements/client/**',).as('response')

        goTo.plusClientsButton()
        cy.wait('@response', {timeout: 10000})
        cy.get('@response').then( xhr => {
            const link = xhr.request.headers.referer
            cy.log(link)
```

link has the value: http://viasphere.localhost/documents/page_elements/client/19537

Obviosly `const link = xhr.request.headers.referer.text()` is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `.replace(/^\D+/g, '')` to extract the number from the url.

```js
cy.intercept(
  'GET',
  'http://viasphere.localhost/documents/page_elements/client/**'
).as('response')

goTo.plusClientsButton()
cy.wait('@response', {timeout: 10000})
cy.get('@response').then((xhr) => {
  const client_id = xhr.request.headers.referer.replace(/^\D+/g, '')
  cy.log(client_id) //prints 19537
})
```

Comment: Oh, damn, I knew about the replace, but I thought It can be applied only to method .text.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the `.then()` Alapan Das provided, you can use cypress commands to perform the same actions.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', 'http://viasphere.localhost/documents/page_elements/client/**',).as('response')

goTo.plusClientsButton()
cy.wait('@response', {timeout: 10000})
  // can access request.headers.referer from .wait()
  .its('request.headers.referer')
  // returns 'http://viasphere.localhost/documents/page_elements/client/'
  .invoke('replace', /^D+/g, '')
  // now you have the link and can print it
  .then(cy.log)
```